# Search not working with nexus-repository conan

Tags: nexus3, conan

I have a nexus server which has conan plugin installed. I am able to connect to nexus remote using conan client. All the commands seem to work fine except for conan search.
If I try to upload something it is working:

```
conan upload OpenSSL/1.0.2l@conan/stable  --all -r nxrm-conan-hosted
```

I get the following output which is all good

```
Uploading OpenSSL/1.0.2l@conan/stable to remote 'nxrm-conan-hosted'
Uploading conanmanifest.txt
[==================================================] 58B/58B 
Uploading conanfile.py  
[==================================================] 18.1KB/18.1KB 
Uploaded conan recipe 'OpenSSL/1.0.2l@conan/stable' to 'nxrm-conan-hosted': http://localhost:8081/repository/conan-hosted/   
Uploading package 1/1: 2b79e5c38fa00890dc9d36d4699d1add085ac085                      
Requesting upload urls...Done!
Uploading conanmanifest.txt 
[==================================================] 4.7KB/4.7KB 
Uploading conaninfo.txt  
[==================================================] 1.2KB/1.2KB      
Uploading conan_package.tgz    
[==================================================] 2.9MB/2.9MB
```

where nxrm-conan-hosted is setup like this:

```
conan remote add nxrm-conan-hosted http://localhost:8081/repository/conan-hosted/ false
```

But, when i search something:

```
conan search -r nxrm-conan-hosted
```

I get the following 404:

```
ERROR:                                                                                                                  <!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                                         
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>404 - Nexus Repository Manager</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>                                                                                                       <script>(new Image).src="http://localhost:8081/favicon.ico?3.16.0-01"</script>                                          <![endif]-->                                                                                                            
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://localhost:8081/favicon-32x32.png?3.16.0-01" sizes="32x32">
      <link rel="mask-icon" href="http://localhost:8081/safari-pinned-tab.svg?3.16.0-01" color="#5bbad5">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://localhost:8081/favicon-16x16.png?3.16.0-01" sizes="16x16">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost:8081/favicon.ico?3.16.0-01">
      <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="http://localhost:8081/mstile-144x144.png?3.16.0-01">
      <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#00a300">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8081/static/css/nexus-content.css?3.16.0-01"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="nexus-header">
         <a href="http://localhost:8081">
            <div class="product-logo">                                                                                                <img src="http://localhost:8081/static/images/nexus.png?3.16.0-01" alt="Product logo"/>                               </div>
            <div class="product-id">
               <div class="product-id__line-1">                                                                                          <span class="product-name">Nexus Repository Manager</span>                                                            </div>
               <div class="product-id__line-2">                                                                                          <span class="product-spec">OSS 3.16.0-01</span>                                                                       </div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="nexus-body">
         <div class="content-header">                                                                                              <img src="http://localhost:8081/static/rapture/resources/icons/x32/exclamation.png?3.16.0-01" alt="Exclamation point" aria-role="presentation"/>                                                                                                <span class="title">Error 404</span>                                                                                    <span class="description">Not Found</span>                                                                            </div>
         <div class="content-body">
            <div class="content-section">                                                                                             Not Found                                                                                                             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
[Remote: nxrm-conan-hosted]
```

I found this issue with regards to the search:
https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-conan/issues/13

Seems like the search feature is not yet implemented in the plugin. I am not completely familiar with the languages of the plugin. In this regard, I would like to ask for some step by step instruction on how to set up the the search end point by creating necessary routes, where to place those routes, communication with the nexus server to send search queries and all.